# Incorrect reference to the equation number in algorithm2e

Tags: equations, numbering, algorithm2e

I want equation number in an algorithm with chapter number included. Here is my code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, latexsym,float,epsfig,subfig}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, breqn}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}

\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\numberwithin{exmp}{chapter}
\numberwithin{lemma}{chapter}
\numberwithin{proposition}{chapter}
\numberwithin{corollary}{chapter}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{First}
    \label{chap_ch1}

    \begin{algorithm}[!h]
        \DontPrintSemicolon
        \SetAlgoLined

            \If{p} {
                \begin{equation}    \label{eq:sclrec1}
                    a = b
                \end{equation}
            }
            \Else {
                \If{t} {
                    \begin{equation} \label{eq:sclrec2}
                    x = y
                    \end{equation}
                }

            }

    \caption{\label{alg:algo} algorithm}
    \end{algorithm}
    Equation~\ref{eq:sclrec1} and Equation~\ref{eq:sclrec2}

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows :

[image: Result of the code]

I don't understand why my references are incorrect. Can anyone please explain ?

[writeLatex Code](https://www.writelatex.com/1057613rwtpyp)

Comment: I guess it is referencing the line numbers.

Comment: an extremely ugly hack: `\begin{equation}\addtocounter{equation}{-1}\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:sclrec1}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conflict between `amsmath` and `algorithm2e` (your example includes a number of packages not relevant to the problem) and only applies to the `equation` environment.  The simplest workaround is to just use `gather` instead.

For `equation` placing text before the equation or in the absence of such just `\leavevmode` will also work:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\label{chap_ch1}

\begin{algorithm}[!h]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetAlgoLined

  \If{p} { Correct reference
      \begin{gather}    \label{eq:sclrec1}
          a = b
      \end{gather}
  }
  \Else {
      \If{t} { \leavevmode
          \begin{equation} \label{eq:sclrec2}
          x = y
          \end{equation}
      }
      \Else {
      \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:sclrec3}
        p = q
      \end{equation}
      }
  }

  \caption{\label{alg:algo} algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
Equation~\ref{eq:sclrec1} and Equation~\ref{eq:sclrec2} are correctly
referenced, equation~\ref{eq:sclrec3} (really 1.3) is not.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following provides a work-around, as well as a better vertical alignment of the equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,algochapter]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}\label{chap_ch1}

\begin{algorithm}[!h]
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetAlgoLined
  \If{p} {
    \hfill\llap{%
      \makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill $a = b$\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\llap{(\theequation)}\label{eq:sclrec1}}}
  }
  \Else {
    \If{t} {
      \hfill\llap{%
        \makebox[\linewidth]{\hfill $x = y$\hfill\refstepcounter{equation}\llap{(\theequation)}\label{eq:sclrec2}}}
    }
}
  \caption{\label{alg:algo} algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

Equation~\eqref{eq:sclrec1} and Equation~\eqref{eq:sclrec2}

\end{document}
```

Each equation is set in a box of width `\linewidth` (thereby disregarding the well-maintain algorithm indentation - perhaps something to improve upon) with the equation exactly in the middle. The equation counter is manually stepped (and made possible to reference) and set.

Since you're loading [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), using `\eqref` provides the required duplicate of the equation number + parentheses.